# Which version of Matlab started supporting 64-bit on Linux/Mac?

Tags: linux, macos, mac, 64-bit, matlab

What is the first Matlab release that fully supports 64-bit? Is it 2010a? I've got 64-bit installations of Linux and Mac OS X, and want to make sure I install a copy of Matlab that takes full advantage of 64-bit and the resulting larger memory support. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be there for Mac since R2009b release.[MATLAB Release history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB#Release_history). Also read, [Why no 64-bit support for Mac OS?](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/161842)

For Linux, I am not very sure but it appears to be supporting 64-bit Linux even before it did in Windows i.e., since 2004. Relevant posts: [64 bit Matlab?](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/76561) and [MATLAB Offers 64-Bit Support for MATLAB on Linux](http://www.embeddedstar.com/press/content/2004/11/embedded17095.html)

Comment: OK. What about for Linux? Thanks.

Comment: I didn't know that when I answered first. Now I have added the info in my answer.